# Avoid Facebook notifications for photo likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-photos

I don't want to see **notifications** in (desktop) Facebook when friends like one of my photos. Is there a way to do this?

There are lots of really similar questions here, but I don't think there's an exact duplicate.

Each time I come back from a trip, I upload an album, say 100 photos. Over the next few days, my notifications box is just a blur of "X liked Y photo". It's just so spammy and not interesting.

Is there any way to avoid this? I've tried FB Purity, but it doesn't seem to have an option for this - unless I'm wrong?

(Just to be extra clear: I'm not trying to prevent people seeing my likes, I'm not trying to avoid generating stories, I'm not trying to avoid seeing likes, and I'm not talking about mobile. Just don't want to see photo likes in my notifications box on desktop Facebook).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in FB Purity with Custom CSS code. The CSS code you need to hide notifications of people liking individual photos is :

```
#fbNotificationsFlyout li[data-gt^='{"notif_type":"like","subtype":"photo"'] {display: none}
```

If you also wanted to hide likes of whole photo albums, you could add the following CSS code:

```
#fbNotificationsFlyout li[data-gt^='{"notif_type":"like","subtype":"photo_album"'] {display: none}
```

To add this code with FB Purity:

**1)** Install the safe, and free [**FB Purity browser add-on**](http://www.fbpurity.com)

**2)** Go to Facebook and open the **FBP** options screen by clicking the "**FBP**" in the top nav bar, or the "**F.B. Purity**" link at the top of the newsfeed.

**3)** Click the "**CSS**" link at the top right of the FBP options screen, which opens the CSS box.

**4)** Copy and paste the above code into the CSS box

**5)** Click the "**Save & Close**" button, to save your changes and refresh the page.

Please note this will just hide the actual notification lines in the drop down menu, it won't alter the counter to reduce the number shown next to the Globe Icon in the top nav bar, so you may receive "ghost notifications" with a number shown next to the globe, but the number of notifications that show when you click the globe won't match as the photo notifications in the drop down will be hidden.

For those who don't know **[FB Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com)** is a browser extension that lets you clean up and customize Facebook the way you want it to be.